# How to specify conditions before performing trigram search in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, fuzzy-search, trigram

I'm fairly new to fuzzy searching and trigrams in PostgreSQL. I have a few hundred thousand products in the database and I want to be able to select products whose name is closest to another product's name.

After a few hours of experimenting and research, I have installed the `pg_trgm` extension and created a trigram index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX simpleproduct_name_lowercase
ON simpleproduct
USING gist(lower(name) gist_trgm_ops);
```

The following query than executes in about 0.07s, which is satisfying for now:

```
SELECT  'coffee' <-> lower(name) as distance, gtin, name
FROM simpleproduct
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10
```

The thing is, I need to further specify what kind of products I want to be searching through. I imagined that if I do that, it will be faster then before because I am not fuzzy searching the whole database but only a specific group of products. For some reason though, if I do e.g. the following:

```
SELECT  'coffee' <-> lower(name) as distance, gtin, name
FROM simpleproduct
WHERE id < 10000
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10
```

... the execution time roughly doubles. Could anybody explain why that is the case? Also, if you are experienced in this area, would you recommend **against** using PostgreSQL and going e.g. with Elastic?

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE? Please post the results at http://explain.depesz.com

Comment: Cheers for your suggestion: [without the further condition](http://explain.depesz.com/s/Brb) and [with the further condition](http://explain.depesz.com/s/NRTl). Thanks a lot in advance!